# VHDL - Successive Approximation Register

Tags: vhdl

I have a question about VHDL code I am attempting to write for a Successive approximation register for an ADC.

In the Code shown below, will DigitalOutTemp be continuously updating throughout the for loop? or will it only recieve the value of OutTemp at the end of the Process?

I think I may have the logic wrong but what I am trying to do is to have DigitalOutTemp going through a Digital to analog Converter and then into a comparator with the Analog signal I am measuring. The Comparator will then feed back into the register.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY SARegister IS
PORT (
    Comparator, Clock                     : IN std_logic;
    DigitalOutFinal, DigitalOutTemp   : OUT std_logic_vector (13 downto 0)
);
END;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioural OF SARegister IS
BEGIN

PROCESS (CompIn, Clock)
    VARIABLE OutTemp : std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(Clock)) THEN
        OutTemp := "10000000000000";

        FOR i IN 13 downto 0 LOOP

            IF (Comparator = '0') THEN
                OutTemp(i) := '0';
            END IF;

            IF (i > 0) THEN
                OutTemp(i - 1) := '1';
            END IF;

            DigitalOutTemp <= OutTemp;

        END LOOP;

        DigitalOutFinal <= OutTemp;

    END IF;

END PROCESS;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear understand about your conversion, you code is too weird. But i will point out what is wrong in your code. **It's not ANSWER** because comment is two narrow to write. Hope that make you code better.

```
PROCESS (CompIn, Clock)
```

This sensitive list may lead to something I don't know because i can't see `CompIn` signal anymore in your code. If you want it's a register, please put only `clock` or `set` or `reset` signal on this list (or `enable` with clock gating.

```
VARIABLE OutTemp : std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(Clock)) THEN
    OutTemp := "10000000000000";

    FOR i IN 13 downto 0 LOOP

        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN
            OutTemp(i) := '0';
        END IF;

        IF (i > 0) THEN
            OutTemp(i - 1) := '1';
        END IF;
```

Two `if` don't lead better result because second will overwrite first. I sure that `OutTemp` with get all `1111..11` after this (even loop).

```
        DigitalOutTemp <= OutTemp;
```

Please not put this assigment in this loop. Even you assign it infinite time,  this process only run  when rising_eadge of clock.

```
    END LOOP;

    DigitalOutFinal <= OutTemp;

END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

I can sure your code CANNOT be compiled because missing CompIn. Even you add CompIn, the result `DigitalOut...` will always `1111...1` (all ones).

Answer (score 0):

> In the Code shown below, will DigitalOutTemp be continuously updating
>   throughout the for loop? or will it only recieve the value of OutTemp
>   at the end of the Process?

Each time you write to DigitalOutTemp the signal will get the new value *scheduled to be updated*.  However the update will not happen until the end of the current delta-cycle (ie after all the processes triggered have finished).

Until that point, if you read the signal (in the same process or in any other process) you are guaranteed to read the same (starting) value.